# Mapping points to polygons in ESRI shape file in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, gis, esri

I have an ESRI shape file with many geographic areas, represented as non-overlapping polygons. I'm trying to map arbitrary points to the polygons which they belong to in Python.

I've looked into storing the polygons in a SQLite database as R-trees, but I think this works if the shapes are rectangles (or if I approximate the polygons by using minimum bounding rectangles).

Is there any way to do this exact calculation with R-trees (or a similar module provided by SQLite)? This way I could store this information as a SQLite database, making it very easy to perform this calculation cross platform.

Comment: I think you will find a much more active GIS community and get a better response for answers over at http://gis.stackexchange.com/